# Determine how app instance is created? By clicking launcher icon or from service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have an application that runs service in background. I have to determine if application instance is created from Service or not **from my Application class.**

Is that possible? Can I get any info from Application instance about how my app run?

Comment: If your service is running, the application instance is already in existence. You cannot recreate it from the Service.

Comment: Hi Raghav, yes, you are right. But when I stop the app from DDMS and an update comes to Service, the instance will be recreated and I need to handle a case like this.

Comment: Please be more specific about the different cases you are trying to distinguish. Your `Application` instance is created when Android creates a process for your application. This can be for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: I am initializing my app from Application class so that I can load data quickly and do some necessary checks before my Activities are visible. However, when service run and connect to my server, there are 2 requests outgoing to the server. I want to combine the two to decrease num of requests. That is why I ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your service you have an **Intent** that gets opened upon certain conditions (when the user taps on the notification, for example)
You could provide a flag with `putExtra` on the Intent from the service. In your activity you read this flag, and if it is set to a particular value you know it has been triggered from the Service.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Yes, I handle notification clicks like this. However, I need to handle my case in Application class, not in an Activity. So, there is not an intent.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to handle it in your Application?

Comment: Please check my 2nd comment above.

Comment: YOu need to consider that the launcher in Android launches an app through an Intent, and for a normal app this Intent is usually associated to an Activity. That's why the Intent object is the one that can contain the most useful information on how it was launched.